# Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'

Tags: express, multer, nest

Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.
Been straggling with this error for 2 days now.
I've tried:

- import "multer"
- import { Multer } from "multer"
- import { Express } from "express"
- Add tsconfig types: ["Multer"]

and yet my backend keeps erroring on build.

[image: code example]

Answer (score 14):

I solved the same issue by adding `@types/multer` to my dependencies.

So either
`yarn add @types/multer` or `npm install --save @types/multer`

Answer (score 12):

After installing `npm install -D @types/multer`, add "Multer" to `compilerOptions` --> `types` property inside your `tsconfig.json` file:

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "types": ["node", "Multer"]     // <-- Add "Multer" here
  }
}
```

Explanation: In your `tsconfig.json` file, possibly there's a `"types"` property specified under `compilerOptions`, which, according to [this typescript definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types), if `types` is specified, only packages listed will be included in the global scope, therefore, if "Multer" was not included there, it won't automatically be included in the global scope, and this is why you're getting an error *Namespace 'global.Express' has no exported member 'Multer'.*

**Shortcut hack:**

*Warning:* This is only a hack to make Multer available in the Express namespace, and you should make sure typings are available to typescript like I explained above.

```
import 'multer'; // a hack to make Multer available in the Express namespace

// ...

async createNewPost(
    // ...
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    // ...
)
```

PS: In production, you may need to move `@types/multer` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` for an unclear reason.

PS2: If you're working with an nx.workspace, make sure to edit the "types" inside tsconfig.app.json under the Nest (API) folder.

*tsconfig.app.json*

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": ["node", "Multer"],    // <-- Add "Multer" here
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "target": "es2015"
    },
    "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: For me, adding "multer" to tsconfig.json worked (notice the starting "M").

Answer (score 0):

If adding `@types/multer` and importing them not helping, try to change the typescript version in IDE.
In VSCode Command Palette -> TypeScript: Select TypeScript version -> Use workspace version.